# How to drag feature to another feature and after change its icon

Tags: javascript, json, vector, openlayers, geojson

I don't know how change the icon automatically when I drag my feature to another one keeping the same coordinates of my first feature .

So when I drag "geojson_etat3" to the second one "geojson_etat4" I'd like to change the icon of the first one to Etat4.png

```
        var geojson_etat3 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("etat3", {
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    externalGraphic: './images/Etat3.png', 
                    graphicWidth: 21, 
                    graphicHeight: 25,
                    graphicYOffset: -24,
                    label : "${name}"
                    } ),

                }),
        projection: epsg4326,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "data/data_etat3.json",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })

        });
        var geojson_etat4 = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("etat4", {
        styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    externalGraphic: './images/Etat4.png', 
                    graphicWidth: 21, 
                    graphicHeight: 25,
                    graphicYOffset: -24,
                    label : "${name}"
                    } ),

                }),
        projection: epsg4326,
        strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
        protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
            url: "data/data_etat4.json",
            format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })

        });
```

Comment: What do you mean by drag a feature to another one. Do you mean that their bounding boxes intersect?

Comment: what I mean is when I slip my item to another and when that is on it, it changes the icon and keep the same coordinates

Comment: So, using the DragFeature control, you would write something in onComplete which will change the icon of the feature being dragged, so long as it is on top of (bounding boxes intersect) another icon?

Comment: i have probem now i can't drag my feature do you have an example code for draging !! i search but in vain

Comment: http://openlayers.org/dev/examples/drag-feature.html Drag feature itself is reasonably straightforward, but what you are asking appears to be something else.